# how to choose between versions in build.gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

if you have a build.gradle file with the line `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`, how do you choose the version of the jar it downloads so that you get the latest one? I've seen a project where it is a 2.2.4 release, but in another project I've seen the same line with a 2.2.5 release.

Comment: do you mean how to specify version for a jar? If so one way is you can simply add as like below -> implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use lockfiles and a version of `+`, or a combination of `major.minor.+` or `major.+`

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:+'
```

For more information on dependency locking: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html

Another approach, and one I'm quite pleased with where available, is using a bill of materials, which specifies versions for a lot of dependencies, by introducing constraints. So where a dependency is used, with no version specified, as in your example, it will get the version the BOM brings in. So for the dependency below, if it is present in the BOM, it will match

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

You're also free to override versions manually, by still specifying the version, should you choose to. And a BOM is like any other dependency, so you can use a mixture of lockfiles and BOMs.

Here's gradle documentation on bill of materials: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Answer (score 5):

Since you dropped the name Spring Boot, I assume the project has been generated [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/). A project generated with the Initializr has two plugins applied:

- [`org.springframework.boot`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot) ([Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/))
- [`io.spring.dependency-management`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management) ([Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/))

`io.spring.dependency-management` is Spring's opinionated way to provide Maven-like dependency management to Gradle builds. It allows to declare dependency versions once and then omit the version when declaring the actual dependency.

The `org.springframework.boot` plugin does the following:

> When you apply the [`io.spring.dependency-management`](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) plugin, Spring Boot’s plugin will automatically [import the `spring-boot-dependencies` bom](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins-dependency-management) from the version of Spring Boot that you are using. This provides a similar dependency management experience to the one that’s enjoyed by Maven users. For example, it allows you to omit version numbers when declaring dependencies that are managed in the bom. To make use of this functionality, simply declare dependencies in the usual way but omit the version number.
>
> (From: [Managing Dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies))

**What does that mean in practice?**

When you generate a project for Spring Boot 2.1.14, your `build.gradle` will look similar to this:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.14.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

The `org.springframework.boot` plugin instructs the `io.spring.dependency-management` to apply the bill of materials (BOM) of [Spring Boot 2.1.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.14.RELEASE). The BOM declares the following version for `spring-boot-starter-web`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.14.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

(From: [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.14.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.14.RELEASE.pom))

And this combination allows to declare the dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web` in the `build.gradle` without providing an actual version:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

If you would change the version of the `org.springframework.boot` Gradle plugin, then a different version that matches the Spring Boot versions would be applied.

You may ask, why this tremendous effort?

> We take an opinionated view of the Spring platform and third-party libraries so you can get started with minimum fuss.

That's why.